# unexpected T_string error - where?

Tags: php, pdo, syntax-error

This piece of code gives me a syntax error, but I can't figure out why.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\Users\user\school\infPOPHP2\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\create_db.php on line 7

line 7 is

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
```

This is the full code

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "competitie";
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS competitie" ;
    $resultaat = $db­>exec($sql);
    $db = NULL;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e­>getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is too localized and thus shouldn't be asked on Stack Overflow. the right question to ask would be `"how can i find a syntax error?"` and `"where can I learn basic PHP syntax?"`.

Comment: So because I am a beginner I don't deserve any help? Then how will I ever learn? To me, this code looks correct, but apparently, it's not. If I can't figure it out and if more advanced people don't want to help me then how can I ever find a solution?

Comment: you're missing the closing php line ?>

Comment: No, sorry I didn't copy the last line on accident. The closing ?> is there.

Comment: technically speaking, you don't need the closing ?> tag, that's not the issue here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check all the `;`'s in the code and replace them with conventional `;`s (ASCII 59).
Don't use fancy editors like Microsoft Word to edit code.